# Штопаный или штопанный — как правильно?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия, удвоенные-буквы

*Не раз штопа**н**ая кожаная куртка* или *не раз штопа**нн**ая куртка*?
Как написать правильно?

Comment: а пуля просвистела?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал "**штопанная**" - по смыслу тут причастие и есть формальный признак - зависимое слово "не раз".

Но беда в том, что не всякое зависимое слово является основанием наверняка считать определение причастием. К таким "пограничным" признакам как раз и относятся некоторые разряды наречий (способа или образа действия, например).

Если считать "не раз" наречием, то можно трактовать как наречие времени (близкое по значение к "долго", "постоянно"), тогда это скорее качество куртки и, значит, "штопаная" может считаться (как вариант) прилагательным и таким образом допускать написание с одним Н.

Но тут "не раз" скорее всего наречие меры или степени - со значением "неоднократно", это придает определению явный характер состояния, а не качества. Поэтому написание с удвоенным Н не должно вызывать вопросов.

Comment: Полностью согласна, это всё-таки причастие. Если прилагательное, то значение "не новый", а "не раз не новый" звучит не по-русски, обстоятельство не раз придаёт глагольность: не раз штопанная куртка-та, которую не раз штопали.

Comment: @Людмила если бы все было так просто, то и вопроса бы не было. Но уже сама проверка заменой на синоним (да еще неточный) не всегда правомерна. Наше любимое раненный/раненый. "Не раз раненый" - неужели ж причастие только потому, что "не раз увечный" - не по-русски? Нет, я все-таки вижу тут более глубокую проблему, которая решается только на основании анализа значения сочетания "не раз" в конкретном контексте.